# Listview does not save items when screen is rotated - Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, rotation, adapter, screen

OK I have a news program that gets data via JSON. It has a custom adapter which includes mainly strings and an image. At the top of the screen there is a search button and editText for the search criteria.  That is not functioning yet, but will be easily fixed later.  Anyway it works fine, but when I rotate the screen the data disappears and you have to press the search button again.  But then really it never does reload the data. I'm hoping it's something in the main activity so I included it here. Any help would be appreciated!

```
package com.example.android.newsreport;

import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NewsReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderCallbacks<List<Story>> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = NewsReportActivity.class.getName();
    private  String NewsApiUrl ="http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=021abbfbc4de4c33b1644057d5f2be58";
    /**
     * Constant value for the Book loader ID. We can choose any integer.
     * This really only comes into play if you're using multiple loaders.
     */
    private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    /** Adapter for the list of books */
    private StoryAdapter mAdapter;
    private StoryAdapter saveStateAdapter;

    /** TextView that is displayed when the list is empty */
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_activity);


        ListView newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        newsListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

        // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of books as input
        mAdapter = new StoryAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Story>());


        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        newsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        /// End Button search
        // Set an item click listener on the ListView, which sends an intent to a web browser
        // to open a website with more information about the selected book.
        newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Find the current book that was clicked on
                Story currentstory = mAdapter.getItem(position);

                // Convert the String URL into a URI object (to pass into the Intent constructor)
                Uri newsUri = Uri.parse(currentstory.getPreviewLink());

                // Create a new intent to view the book URI
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, newsUri);

                // Send the intent to launch a new activity
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });

        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Story>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // Create a new loader for the given URL
        return new StoryLoader(this, NewsApiUrl);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Story>> loader, List<Story> bookworms) {
        // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Set empty state text to display "No books found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_stories);

        // Clear the adapter of previous book data
        mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link Book}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (bookworms != null && !bookworms.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(bookworms);
            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Story>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();

    }
    public void goQuery(View view){
        EditText mySearchTextView = findViewById(R.id.searchEdit);
        if (mySearchTextView.getText().length() < 1) return;
        // ListView newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //  TextView bookwormTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);



        View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        NewsApiUrl = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=021abbfbc4de4c33b1644057d5f2be58";
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get details on the currently active default data network
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
        android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.destroyLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID);
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // If there is a network connection, fetch data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

// Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
            // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
            // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).

            loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        } else {
            // Otherwise, display error
            // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
            loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Update empty state with no connection error message
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mySearchTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }


}
```

Comment: There are many things that are not right here. To name a few, a) you are using a LIstView instead of a RecyclerView; b) you have all the business logic in your activity; c) you are not persisting any data on rotation.
You should look at the MVVM architecture and offload your business logic to a viewmodel, just doing that will take care of handling rotation and not having to refetch the data when the activity is recreated.

Comment: OK, not sure how to go about that. So I guess I'll just keep taking the online classes and maybe this will eventually be covered. Thanks.

Comment: Funny thing is this is a Udacity project that pretty much uses the same code as a Book App. Just had to change the Json process and change the names of different files and variables. The Book App works when the phone is rotated. I've compared the code file to file and it looks the same. There has to be something I'm overlooking and it bothers the hell out of me!